# Copy constructor for dynamic object in C++

Tags: c++, object, dynamic, copy-constructor

I want to one methodology regarding copy-constructor

```
class A {
    int *a;
   public :
        A():a(0){
                      a = new int;
                       *a =0;}
           A (const A & ob) {
            cout<<"In side copy constructor ..."<<endl;
            a = new int;
            *a = *ob.a;
           }
          ~A() {  cout <<"IN side destructor ..."<<endl;delete a;}
          void setdata(int ip) { *a = ip;}
          int getdata() { return *a;}
     };
int main() {
  A *dob1 = new A();
  dob1->setdata(5);
  A sob1= *dob1; //copy constructor gets called;

 //but for this case copy constructor will not be called
 // how should i write copy constructor for this case
  A *dob2 = dob1; //whether copy constructor will be called or not 

   cout<<endl;
      cout<<" dob1 data "<< dob1->getdata()<<endl;
        cout<<" sob1 data " << sob1.getdata()<<endl;
      cout<<" dob2 data "<< dob2->getdata()<<endl;

   delete dob1;
   return 0;
}
```

So how to create a copy constructor will be called for this case.

Please reply me.

Comment: Please fix your indents.

Comment: Throw away your copy constructors. Use `std::vector` instead of C style arrays and it will magically work. Your problem is not copy constructors, your problem is that you are not too familiar with C style arrays. Just don't use them.

Comment: `A *dob2 = dob1;` This assigns a pointer. There is no copy involved. `A *dob2 = new A(*dob1)` would create a copy, and probably a memory leak too.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but since I personally dislike downvoters who don't leave comments I'll point out what's bad about your question: 1. Excessive amount of grammatical mistakes. 2. The question would be answered by working through a C++ tutorial.

Comment: @Peter I'd add poor indentation to the list.

Comment: You should get out of the habit of using `new` for everything. Object semantics (including copying) make more sense when you're dealing with objects, rather than introducing unnecessary pointers. (You'd also avoid bugs like the double-deletion of `a` in this example if you didn't try to juggle pointers in this error-prone manner.)

Answer (score 2):

In `A *dob2 = dob1;` the object isn't copied, the pointer is.

`A*` is a whole different type. The pointer `dob2` will point to `dob1`, but it is not an object itself, so don't expect a copy constructor be be called.

If you did `A* dob2 = new A(dob1);` the copy constructor would be called, an object will be created, and `dob2` would point to it, but it still wouldn't be the object itself, but a pointer.

Comment: Thanks. Then please let me know what is the best way to create a new dynamic object by using existing dynamic object without any memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

Handling the dynamic memory using raw pointers is cumbersome. A better approach would be using STL containers like `std::vector, std::deque` or handling the dynamic memory using a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr, std::shared_ptr`.

If someone really wants to know how to create a new dynamic object using another existing dynamic object by copy constructor then have a look at the below code. Use with caution!

```
class A {
    public:
        A() : a{ new int {0} } { std::cout << "Inside default constructor ..." << endl;}
        A(const A& ob) {
            std::cout << "Inside copy constructor ..." << endl;
            a = new int;
            *a = *ob.a;
        }
        ~A() { 
            std::cout << "Inside destructor ..." << endl; 
            delete a; 
            a = nullptr;
        }
        void setdata(int ip) { *a = ip; }
        int getdata()        { return *a; }

    private:
        int* a;
};

int main() {
    // Dynamic Object  - 1
    A* dob1 = new A();     // Calls default constructor
    dob1->setdata(5);

    // Stack Object   - 1
    A sob1 = *dob1;         // Calls copy constructor

    // Dynamic Object - 2
    A* dob2 = new A(*dob1); // Calls copy constructor

    cout << " dob1 data " << dob1->getdata() << endl;
    cout << " sob1 data " << sob1.getdata() << endl;
    cout << " dob2 data " << dob2->getdata() << endl;

    delete dob2;
    delete dob1;
}
```

Output:

```
Inside default constructor ...
Inside copy constructor ...
Inside copy constructor ...
 dob1 data 5
 sob1 data 5
 dob2 data 5
Inside destructor ...
Inside destructor ...
Inside destructor ...
```